# Presentation mic to laptop then HDMI

Tags: audio

I am presently using a laptop with Windows 10 to present PowerPoints (sometimes with audio), via HDMI to a TV with sound bar.

This works great but I now want to use a mic connected to the laptop to send the presenters voice to the TV and soundbar over the HDMI.

Simple question and hopefully a simple answer.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel.

Go to Sound.

Click on the recording tab.

Right click your microphone and click on Properties.

Go to the Listen tab.

Tick the box that says "Listen to this device"

Click Apply

[settingsscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndeYK.png)